# Insert macro w/ desired File Name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, ms-office

Here's my code below, my problem is i want to put my desired filename when creating an document.. But i don't know how. Can you help me.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim odoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWModule As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim sCode As String
    Dim oCommandBar As Office.CommandBar
    Dim oCommandBarButton As Office.CommandBarControl


    ' Create an instance of Word, and show it to the user.
    oWord = New Word.Application()

    ' Add a Document.
    odoc = oWord.Documents.Add

    ' Create a new VBA code module.
    oWModule = odoc.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisDocument")

    sCode = "Sub FileSaveAs" & vbCr & _
       "   msgbox ""Save As has been Disabled!"" " & vbCr & _
       "end sub"

    ' Add the VBA macro to the new code module.
    oWModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)

    oWord.Visible = True
    ' Set the UserControl property so that Excel does not shut down.
    'oWord.UserControl = True

    ' Release the variables.
    oCommandBarButton = Nothing
    oCommandBar = Nothing
    oWModule = Nothing
    odoc = Nothing
    oWord = Nothing

    ' Force garbage collection.
    GC.Collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

can you run odoc.saveas after adding the document?
In Powerpoint, that assigns the filename-

Comment: As you can see i disabled the save as, so when i create i have an openfiledialog and savefiledialog so that it will be saved automatically. And i want to start my document with the name i have wrote in the savefiledialog.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line of code

```
' Add a Document.
    odoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    odoc.Name = "DesiredNameHere"
```

to rename the word document.